# Memtest with Ubuntu 12.04 live CD

Tags: 12.04, live-usb

I've probably missed something but I can't find the `memtest` option when booting from my Ubuntu 12.04 Live USB.

Could someone please tell me how to get to it?

Comment: If you have an UEFI bios and you want to test your memory for errors you need to downlaod the seperate image from http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm. The utility on the Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB does not work with computers with a UEFI BIOS.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to boot from live CD or USB. Press **and hold** any key while your computer is booting.

Press 'F6', a language menu will pop up, select English and press enter.  You will then be presented with the option menu.

[image]

The options will be

- Try Ubuntu without installing
- Install Ubuntu
- Check Disk for Defects
- Test memory
- Boot form First Hard disk

If you select Test Memory you will be presented with another menu that will allow you to select which test(s) you want to run.

---

F.Y.I. Check Disk for defects will check the installation media for defects(not the hard drive)

Comment: I don't know whether that applies to Ubuntu 12.04 but with either 14.04 or 16.04 I had no luck seeing a "memory test" option when booting from a Live USB created with "USB Creator" (command line: `usb-creator-gtk`). Instead, when the live USB was created with UNetbootin: https://unetbootin.github.io/. See this relevant answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/848772/89663

Comment: I also solved by directly downloading [memtest](http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) and installing on usb with rufus