# Boot failure - nothing works

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-failure

Overnight, my ubuntu installation (latest LTS version) has stopped working.

Apart from automatic updates, I never made any changes to the system. As of yesterday, the computer starts extremely slowly, eventually takes me to the GRUB screen, and after choosing the operating system, simply stops on a light purple screen. Recovery boot does not work.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: [This question may help you.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90045/how-do-i-investigate-boot-and-partition-issues)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the power cable, open the case, touch a metal component to ensure you have no static charge in your body, and unseat and then reseat the memory modules and the graphics card (if it's not integrated into the motherboard) - you may have a case of thermal socket expansion. As the machine heats up in during use and then cools down after being turned off, the memory modules and graphics card tend to move ever so slightly in their slots. Over time the movement causes the component to lost its contact with the motherboard. Once the machine is booting again, choose the option to run a memtest from the boot screen.

Memtest : [Memtest with Ubuntu 12.04 live CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187573/memtest-with-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd)

Thermal socket expansion (aka chip creep) : [Wikipedia link](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=thermal%20socket%20creep&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_creep&ei=K_y-UIPkDeuz0QX-1IDYDQ&usg=AFQjCNHJWLpoxlEH_Vas5cpIkQ640mbXMg)

Comment: Hey, thanks. I have never done anything of that sort before - it's a bit of a scary notion, but it all fails, I will certainly try. Is chip creep likely to happen on a device that is barely a few months old? Also, I can see all my hard drive partitions and such from a live session, does that make a difference?

Comment: Hmm, if you can get as far as a live session then your hardware is okay. Chip creep should not happen on a newish device, only years later. When you say 'recovery boot does not work', please provide us with the exact message(s) shown on screen - take a pad and pen and write them down then post here for us.

Comment: For this occasion, I chose to backup my files, wipe the entire ubuntu install with gparted (leaving the space unallocated) and reinstalling from live USB. Probably not the most elegant solution, but the cleanest and, for me, the simplest, as I am not great with code and such. I just hope it won't happen again.

HH

Comment: Cool, sometimes a clean install is just the fastest way.

Comment: Or not.

It worked for 1 day. Now, I can not boot any more. Instead,  I get the "unknown filesystem. Grub rescue" message. To make it worse, live session does not work, neither from CD, nor from USB.

I have no idea what to do.

Do you?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm out of ideas on this. As a last resort, is it possible for you to swap out the hard drive and motherboard and try reinstalling again? Is the machine still under warranty?