# Memtest86+ options are missing in Grub menu

Tags: grub2, 13.04, memtest

I had the same problem as @coversnail here: [How can I add the Memtest86+ options back to the Grub menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126160/how-can-i-add-the-memtest86-options-back-to-the-grub-menu)

The problem is: I just can choose between older kernel versions and the actual Ubuntu version in GRUB. There are no other options.

I want to run `memtest86+`. It is installed and in `/etc/grub.d/`, but it is not in GRUB itself. I am kind of confused.

Comment: memtest86 5.0 is available for 15.10, backport to 14.04 yet to be done - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/memtest86+/+bug/1234612  #8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Grub Customizer.  Grub Customizer is a graphical settings manager for GRUB2.

To install,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Or just check out their [website](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer).

To add the memtest entries see images below, and the text.

[image]
[image]
[image]

First Entry

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  b4d22d74-d1db-44c3-a834-e879263662f5
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b4d22d74-d1db-44c3-a834-e879263662f5
fi
linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
```

Second Entry

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  b4d22d74-d1db-44c3-a834-e879263662f5
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b4d22d74-d1db-44c3-a834-e879263662f5
fi
linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
```

**Note: Now the above information is correct, but keep in mind that memtest will not work in grub2-uefi . This is because UEFI does not support launching 16-bit binaries and memtest is a 16-bit binary. Thats also the reason why there is no linux16 command/module in grub2 uefi.**

Also you may want to look at [memtest86+ fails on efi systems](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/memtest86+/+bug/883017).

Comment: There are 4 partitions to choose... I do not exactly know which is affected by memtest. 1 dev/sda and 3 dev/sdb...

Comment: Why exactly is insmod referring to ext2 when I only got partitions using ext4, vfat and swap?

Comment: ext2 covers ext2, ext3 and ext4. `/boot/grub`, is where the Grub 2 modules are stored, you will find ext2.mod. There is no ext4.mod

Comment: Ok, after trying the above mentioned I get following errors: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/--ctayCbzuLg/UcwCys6kOdI/AAAAAAAABH8/GTOyUgICCsM/w1044-h217-no/IMG_9785.JPG

Comment: You un-accepted the answer, Why? Then you post an error message that is not in English.  How I'm suppose to further help you?

Comment: Hey Mitch, the thing is that I did not manage to run memtest, because this error came. It actually says "device not found" plus the device and "linux16 could not be found" -  "press any key to continue"

Hence, the answer is not yet a solution, I un-accepted the answer. I do really appreciate your help!

Comment: The thing is: I managed to bring memtest to grub - but memtest is not working... :/

Comment: Can you please give me the complete message in English?

Comment: Error: no such device: b4d22d74-d1db-44c3-a834-e879263662f5.
Error: command »linu16« could not be found.

Press any key to continue.

Comment: Do you have UEFI BIOS?  I'm going to be away for a few hours, but I will get back to you.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is kind of the problem why my system crashes (kernel panic) - that's why I wanted to run memtest. Cheers.

Comment: See note I added in my answer.  I'll leave the decision about the answer up to you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Much appreciated. That's why I love the Ubuntu community. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but it still comes up in searches, so I'm going to give a solution.

Most distros supply memtest86+. It is not compatible with UEFI, because UEFI does not support 16 bit . However, PassMark Memtest86 (ver. 5 or later) supports UEFI.

First, obtain the memtest files. Download the USB boot image. http://memtest86.com/download.htm Next, extract the files from the image. I burned the image to a flash drive to facilitate installing on multiple computers.

Second, install memtest86. I made a 500MB partition at the end of my HDD, and formatted to FAT32. Then copied all files from flash drive to this partition. Note: it is possible to install to your EFI directory, but files need to be renamed to avoid overwriting existing boot files.

Third, configure grub2-efi menu entry. There are many ways to add an entry, but the safest way that survives update-grub follows. Using root privileges create file /etc/grub.d/39_memtest, and set it executable. (Note: changing the number in the file name changes the position it appears in the grub menu. DO NOT make it lower than 6 to insure that header and theme run first)

Next make the contents of the file:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Adding Memtest86" >&2

exec tail -n +3 $0

menuentry "Memtest86" {

chainloader (hdx,y)/efi/boot/bootx64.efi

}

EOF
```

*Replace (hdx,y) with your appropriate HDD and partition information.

Then run update-grub You should now have a menu entry that boots into Memtest86