# cannot add memtest86 in Grub menu

Tags: grub2

I had already seek solution in:

[How can I add the Memtest86+ options back to the Grub menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126160/how-can-i-add-the-memtest86-options-back-to-the-grub-menu)

[Memtest86+ options are missing in Grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312304/memtest86-options-are-missing-in-grub-menu)

However, they still can't solve my problem...

what drives me crazy most is the command "update-grub" only shows like below, and memtest86 is missing:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
Found memdisk: /boot/memdisk
Imagepath /boot/images not found
done
```

i tried manually execute `/etc/grub.d/20_memtest86` and found it printed nothing..
but i think it should print some code so that it can modify grub.cfg, right?

it there anyone have solution?

thanks a lot!!

Comment: Check if it's installed `apt-cache policy memtest86+`

Answer (score 0):

Memtest86+ does not work in UEFI mode because it is a 16-bit program.  I think there is an alternate version of Memtest86 that will work in UEFI mode - but it is not open source (see [www.memtest86.com/download.htm](http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm)). Or you can switch to legacy boot mode and Memtest86+ will work and grub will run it.