# No memory test option on Grub menu

Tags: 15.04, diagnostic

How do I run a memory test on Ubuntu 15.04? There in no option for that in the Grub menu. There are only options to boot in recover mode and nothing more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the memtest option on the 12.04 64-bit live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/258991/where-is-the-memtest-option-on-the-12-04-64-bit-live-cd)