# Memtest86+ does not work on efi system. Is there an alternative way?

Tags: uefi, memtest

It shows "unknown command linux16" when I run memtest86+ on efi system.

Comment: You need to use a plain set up of memtest86+ from their website.

Comment: Bit more information in my answer to a very similar question than the suggested duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/a/681290/40581

Answer (score -3):

Memtest doesn't work with an UEFI system, and don't try it with bios compatiblity mode! Insted you have to use the windows memory testing utility.