# Memtest86+ does not start on Lenovo z5070

Tags: memtest

I would like to test my RAM.
I have booted live USB with the latest Ubuntu and used it for accessing of memtest86+, but testing did not start.
Note: this USB had worked fine on other my laptop of another model. (the memtest86+ had started there automatically). Can someone describe why this happens and how to workaround this? Thanks a lot
[screen of not workable memtest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0UI7.jpg)

Comment: Memtest86+ works only in BIOS mode. If you want memtest in UEFI mode, see this link, [Memtest86 works in UEFI mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917961/can-i-boot-memtest86-if-im-using-uefi/917998#917998).

Answer (score 1):

Need to press F1 for starting of memtest on my laptop
Worth to mention that it starts automatically on other notebook.

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing your solution :-) Please add information about the version of Ubuntu (for example the name of the iso file).