# Configure Ubuntu 18.04 to boot similarly to the liveUSB version

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb

I have a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro notebook with dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (encrypted with luks) and Windows 10 Pro. I brought it in my trip to Bali with me. After a week, Ubuntu doesn't boot anymore. I get some CPU errors, hardware errors and it's driving me nuts.

See systemd log here: https://pastebin.com/v1WUQ5Wz

What I get immediately when I boot, before luks asks for the password is the CPU error:

```
Okt 06 12:46:12 travel kernel: smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz (family: 0x6, model: 0x45, stepping: 0x1)
Okt 06 12:46:12 travel kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
Okt 06 12:46:12 travel kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: ae0000000040110a
Okt 06 12:46:12 travel kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR ffb07740 MISC 178a0000086 
Okt 06 12:46:12 travel kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:40651 TIME 1570365956 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 25
```

After entering the password to decrypt the disc, I get these errors:

```
Okt 06 12:46:13 travel kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.CFAN], AE_NOT_FOUND (20181213/psargs-330)
Okt 06 12:46:13 travel kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_TRT]
Okt 06 12:46:13 travel kernel: No Arguments are initialized for method [_TRT]
Okt 06 12:46:13 travel kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.IETM._TRT, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181213/psparse-531)
```

I googled around and yes, it seems this can be caused by an hw error, overheating, fan not working properly... but **the thing is that Windows just works fine**. So now for browsing, managing pictures etc. I'm using Windows and I have no issues. So even if there is an hw error, I don't really have time now to investigate the cause etc. **If I boot with the Ubuntu 18.04.3 liveUSB it works just fine**. **I just want linux to boot like the liveUSB one**. If I run `dmesg` after booting the liveUSB, I can see the same hw errors, but the liveUSB was able to boot just fine and it works fine...

**A pragmatical approach for me is to install a kernel similar to the one used in the liveUSB**, and/or set grub options to boot in a similar way. I think the liveUSB has more modules or is configured to run in a less strict way, basically ignore errors and go on booting no matter what. I want this in my linux too.

Once booted in the liveUSB I can mount my luks encrypted disk and chroot into it. I tried already to install the latest kernel, but that didn't help (same CPU errors).

A friend told me it may be that **there may be some checks that prevent the system from booting to avoid overheating and fry my hardware**. But those checks seems disabled in the liveUSB, so again as in my question I'd like to take my chances and disable what prevents from booting and just boot.

Can you guide me to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the memory with [memtest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917961/can-i-boot-memtest86-if-im-using-uefi/917998#917998)? It is possible that some memory location is bad, and your installed Ubuntu tries to use it, while Windows and your live Ubuntu is not using it. Anyway, whatever is wrong, you may want to create a [persistent live drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent) with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but yes I did the memtest full test and no issues were found. As the logs suggest it's not a memory issue, but likely a hardware issue. I will check how to make a persistent live drive, but I wonder if there is a way to boot like a live USB using my hard disk and not an external memory storage...

Comment: A persistent live system can be in a USB drive, or in an internal drive, or a combination. Boot into a USB drive, but have the partition for persistence in the internal drive. Ubuntu will use the first partition it finds with a label `casper-rw` for persistence, so to avoid confusion, have only one such partition. If you make a persistent live USB drive with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), I suggest that you re-label it's `casper-rw` partition for example to `casper-rw0` and then create a partition in your internal drive with the label `casper-rw` and an `ext4` file system.

Comment: Or, if you are prepared to overwrite Windows (after backup of the files you can't afford to lose), you can let **mkusb** install the persistent live system completely into your internal drive. But I repeat that everything will be overwritten in that case.

Comment: This link may also be useful: 'Simple persistence' at [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/sp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/sp). It describes in details how to create a system which boots from a USB drive and has persistence in a a `casper-rw` partition and maybe also a `home-rw` partition in the internal drive.

Comment: Unluckily I cannot afford to lose my (working) Windows installation. Eventually what I could do (slightly different approach) is to install grub on a usb stick, and install a kernel in the same stick, but configure the grub entry to use my notebook hard disk root partition (with my home folder and all my programs). What makes it a bit more complicated is that my notebook HD it's encrypted with LUKS.

Comment: I see, and I agree, that encryption makes things more complicated. So you can run Ubuntu from a USB drive - live-only, persistent live or installed (like into an internal drive) - in a fast USB 3 pendrive or an SSD in an external box - or some hybrid system where you combine the features of different ways to boot Ubuntu.