# Xubuntu did not load

Tags: xubuntu

After switching on, Xubuntu crashed. There was Xubuntu logo and moving arrow for a long long time. After hitting Esc key, I got this message. And finally I had to switch off and on. This happened quite often. From attached image and Neofetch are supporting details. I have been being with Xubuntu for a few months, this problem never happened in Fedora. Why didn't Xubuntu load and then crashed ?

[image: Click to see image here]

```
office001@office001 
------------------- 
OS: Xubuntu 21.10 x86_64 
Host: HP Laptop 14-ck0xxx 
Kernel: 5.13.0-22-generic 
Uptime: 1 hour, 33 mins 
Packages: 1780 (dpkg) 
Shell: bash 5.1.8 
Resolution: 1366x768, 2560x1080 
DE: Xfce 4.16 
WM: Xfwm4 
WM Theme: Greybird 
Theme: Greybird [GTK2/3] 
Icons: elementary-xfce-darker [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
Terminal Font: Monospace 12 
CPU: Intel Pentium Silver N5000 (4) @ 2.700GHz 
GPU: Intel GeminiLake [UHD Graphics 605] 
Memory: 1343MiB / 7714MiB
```

Comment: "[Failed] Failed to start Flush journal to persistent storage" - I this an installed system or a live or persistent live system? Can you specify when it is happening: Randomly? at cold boot? at reboot? Did the problems start after some update or installation of a new program? Have you checked the health status of the drive and of the RAM? Is it a laptop or desktop computer, if laptop, does it make a difference, if connected to the grid (to charge the battery), or running on battery?

Comment: Are you willing to download and run the [system-info script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/) and let it upload the report file to a pastebin, so that we can see details about your computer hardware and software?

Comment: 1. It happened in morning cold boot lately without any updates in the day before.
2. I've never checked the health status of the drive and of the RAM.
3. Even this is laptop but it's like PC for I connect to the grid all the time. It'd run on battery only when the electricity tripped.
4. Sorry, I don't know **system-info script** for I'm an ordinary user.

Comment: We still don't know enough in order to tell what is wrong and how to fix it. If the computer is sometimes booting correctly, I suggest that you keep trying and when it is up and running, please download and run the the [system-info script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/) and let it upload the report file to a pastebin. It is developed by people at the Ubuntu Forums in order to make it easier to help new users. If it does not boot any more, please download a current Xubuntu iso file, make a USB boot drive and try to boot into it. If it works, run the system-info script from there.

Comment: Next, booted from USB boot drive, please check the internal drive's S.M.A.R.T. information and the root file system according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972978/fsck-reports-that-filesystem-still-has-errors/972983#972983). Then boot into BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode) and run memtest from the grub menu to check the RAM. If you can only boot into UEFI mode you need another version of the memtest tool. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917961/can-i-boot-memtest86-if-im-using-uefi/917998#917998).