# Warning after sudo apt upgrade

Tags: boot, memtest

Can it cause problem?

```
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; and I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do.  You do ask "*can it cause problem*", but I see only warning messages, and no actual error. When do you see the message? Are you trying to use memtest86?  Details in the title and your question shouldn't exist in the title as the title may not be readable when the page is viewed on some devices (not everyone uses PCs with large screens, or small screens & small fonts..)

Comment: System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
command: sudo apt upgrade
"when i executed this command i got the following message"

Comment: Please add additional details to your question (*you can edit your own question*).  When that's done I can remove/delete my comment (*comments are intended for us to ask you; your reply is via edits to your question*) as a cleaner question without comments tends to get faster answers.

Comment: Please, open your terminal and type `sudo apt upgrade` then copy the entire output from the command line then edit your question and paste the output.

Comment: Memtest is a tool to test if the RAM (random access memory cards) is working correctly. It is not used at all when Ubuntu is running, so it cannot cause any problem for Ubuntu. The only problem is that you cannot make memtest86+ work in UEFI mode, but if you can boot the computer in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode), you can use it. There is free but non-FOSS version memtest86 (without +), that works also in UEFI mode. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917961/can-i-boot-memtest86-if-im-using-uefi/917998#917998).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I boot memtest86+ if I'm using UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917961/can-i-boot-memtest86-if-im-using-uefi)

Comment: I just see your question which is about a month old. A few days ago I answered a [recent question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414245/590937) which is almost the same as yours. Take a look at the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1414333/590937), it should be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Open your Terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) then type...

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

then add this line:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

to the grub configurations. Then in the terminal run...

```
sudo update-grub
```

then reboot.