# Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2

I am using Ubuntu 23.04 and while upgrading i get some errors i don't understand.

```
sudo apt upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic
The following packages have been kept back:
  gdm3 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-4.0 libcupsfilters2 libcupsfilters2-common
  libgdm1 libgtk-4-1 libgtk-4-bin libgtk-4-common libgtk-4-media-gstreamer
  libppd2 libppd2-common qemu-block-extra qemu-system-common qemu-system-data
  qemu-system-gui qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 12.2 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 277827 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic (5.19.0-40.41) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-40-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-23-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-20-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
error: out of memory.
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
Syntax error at line 267
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic package post-removal script subprocess 
returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

what is the problem here

Comment: Regarding os-prober see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1414333/590937), that's not an error but a warning. There is a problem with `/etc/default/grub` or a file in `/etc/grub.d/`. Please add the output of `cat /etc/default/grub` via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1472871/edit) to your question. Did you edit any file in `/etc/grub.d/`? If so, post the contents of that file too, please. Take a look at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new` at line 267 to check which file in `/etc/grub.d/` produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

os-prober has been disabled, you have to edit `/etc/default/grub`
to add: `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` and run `sudo update-grub`

[related](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/warning-os-prober-will-not-be-executed-to-detect-other-bootable-partitions/57849/2)

Comment: Will this fix the errors the user is seeing?