# What is the best way to add memtest86 version 10.1.009 to Ubuntu Live or Ubuntu desktop so that it boots across five different computers

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have been having problems consistently that the grub-install phase fails during installation of the Ubuntu 20.4 LTS.  Also if I copy the downloaded image directly to disk without a USB interface cable, often the image will not load, even the Live version.  I get an error sometimes that the operating system is not found.

I have this link to start with and I am hoping to find out more information to get this resolved once and for ever.  I have five computers that I want to consistently work for the EFI grub menu coming up at the beginning (so it can be amended of course to add additional boot options).

So far these are the links:

[isohybrid.1.html](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/isohybrid.1.html)
[mkisofs.1.html](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/mkisofs.1.html)

I am open to suggestions, please, from the community on how to approach this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/48535/) and [Can I boot memtest86+ if I'm using UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/917961/), especially [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1448217/)

Comment: @karel  Thank you for your suggestions.  I am still looking into them, and I appreciate your efforts.  I have different disks for each of the different computers right now.  I want to have a single disk that I can copy for all of the machines to work from.  All of the machines boot Ubuntu Liver EFI from the USB drive image (from Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator using the ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso) when the BIOS is setup properly.  It is probably not too much of a stretch to all boot from a single SATA connection internally also.  The main problem is that I need an ISO image for booting.