# Memtested86 need a 16-bit boot

Tags: grub2

Memtest86 is a memory diagnostic tool that runs independently of the operating system. It tests the computer's RAM to detect any errors or faults that may be causing system instability or crashes. How to fix my problem please?

[image]

Comment: A new version works in UEFI mode. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917961/can-i-boot-memtest86-if-im-using-uefi/917998#917998).

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; my box is a semi-recent box (*purchased last month in fact*) & memtest86 works on it, but our releases may differ & I don't know yours.

Comment: I think the name of the package that you're using is memtest86+, which is a fork of memtest86.

Answer (score 1):

Memtester is a userspace utility for testing the memory subsystem for faults. In comparison to memtest86 or PCMemTest you do not need to reboot the computer to test for memory faults.

Memtester can also be told to test memory starting at a particular physical address.

To install Memtester in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install memtester
```

---

PCMemTest is a standalone memory tester for x86 and x86-64 architecture computers. It provides a more thorough memory check than that provided by BIOS memory tests.

PCMemTest can be loaded and run either directly by a PC BIOS (legacy or UEFI) or via an intermediate bootloader that supports the Linux 16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit, or EFI handover boot protocol. It should work on any Pentium class or later 32-bit or 64-bit CPU.

PCMemTest is a fork and rewrite of Memtest86+, which in turn was a fork of Memtest86.

To install PCMemTest in Ubuntu 22.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install pcmemtest
```

Comment: +1; `memtester` is new for me. Thanks :-)