# Ubuntu 20.04 has experienced internal error

Tags: 20.04, error-handling

Ubuntu-newbie here. I'm getting internal error-messages regarding few different things. Most frequent is internal error regarding Gnome control center. This happens basically every time after computer screen goes to sleep and I wake pc up. How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: If you are experiencing "a few different problems" solving the most frequent of the group is unlikely to solve them all. However, it IS possible that you have faulty RAM. You might find https://askubuntu.com/a/952326/225694 useful.