# Navigator crashing a lot on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, 22.04, cuda

I have got a new pc with the the following specs:

Processor AMD Ryzen 9, NVidia GPU GeForce RTX 4070 (cuda version 12.1, driver 530.41.03) , and 64 Gb of RAM DDR4.

I believe the specs to be quiet good for the PC to keep crashing when using chrome or Modzilla navigator everytime. I mention that I also have a dual boot, windows and Ubuntu in separate disks.
When the navigator crashes, I always have to do hard-reboot, after that I get a similar issue to the following [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377314/kernel-panic-and-bad-page-state-in-process-swapper-error) (`Bad page state in process swapper` and `Clearing orphaned inode` )

I really don't know if this issue is related to software or hardware problem, as suggested in the same  [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377314/kernel-panic-and-bad-page-state-in-process-swapper-error), I runned a memory test using [Memtest](https://itslinuxfoss.com/run-memtest-ubuntu-22-04/), no problems detected.
[image]
Other random information is that I get the following message when I run the `sudo apt update` command:
[image]