# Cannot open programs/ run downloads

Tags: 12.04, skype, downloads

So I'm not too familiar with Linux and I began to use Ubuntu to get familiar with it, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and this problem began occurring when my tower fell over last night. I used to be able to open programs such as Skype, and run downloads however now it does not seem to work. I am getting no error messages, just nothing happens.

Comment: What do you mean by "run downloads"? How did you install Skype?

Comment: I installed Skype through terminal with apt-get - this was before things stopped working. By running downloads I mean when clicking a button to download a file it doesn't add to current downloads.

Comment: It seems you are having a hardware problem -hopefully fixable, after your PC fell down. I recommend booting your PC with a Live CD/USB and run any scan disk utility.

Comment: If it's an hardware problem, we can't help.If it's a software problem, probably that the data/partition is corrupted, the only solution is reinstalling skype or maybe OS.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the askUbuntu forum. To be honest your question requires further description of the problem, so we can give you some valuable feedback.

Anyhow, I since you mentioned that your tower fall over, I would say that there is a chance that your hard disk was damaged. Especially if the PC was turned on at that moment.

To check your hard disk for any problems, you can use the 'Disk Utility' in Ubuntu.

Howto:  [Click here and go to 'Checking you HDD or SDD' section](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317241/can-i-use-ubuntu-to-diagnose-hard-drive-or-ram-problems-in-windows)

Also you can force a file system check on the next reboot you perform.

Use the following command to do so. Note that this takes some time to complete.

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

Hope that helps :-)