# Unable to boot from hard drive after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, inspiron

My apologies if I've overlooked the answer elsewhere on this board. I have spent the last almost two weeks on and off trying to resolve this issue: can't successfully boot up hard drive after indication of 'successful installation' from live media disk. Every attempt gives me the trace run ending with the `Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed` error message. I have attempted as many of the Grub parameter alterations as I have come across as possible fixes to no avail. I am thoroughly comfortable working with Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu on laptops in the past both as a dual boot with Windows and as a standalone OS with no problems prior to this.

My hardware: Dell Inspiron 1501 with Sempron 3500+, 2GB RAM, 60GB hard drive, with Ubuntu 13.10 the only OS installed.

My pastebin file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7231541/

I refuse to give up! Please help me! Thanks in advance for any help!

Note: don't mind admitting that I may be overlooking something simple. Therefore, if there is someone who knows for SURE how to resolve this issue, please break it down in a step-by-step way for the benefit of anyone else besides myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well that sounds bad but you would need to do three things to make sure.

1. With the LiveCD run the **Memtest** option in the main LiveCD boot menu. This app will test to make sure your memory is OK. More information about it in [Can I use Ubuntu to diagnose hard drive or RAM problems in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317241/can-i-use-ubuntu-to-diagnose-hard-drive-or-ram-problems-in-windows/317292#317292)
2. Next, if you can boot to the LiveCD Desktop (Run Ubuntu without installing it). You can run the Disk utility to check the SMART of the hard drive.
3. If the 2 options above are OK we then download from another PC another ISO image and burn it in another CD/DVD with write check. With this new burned CD/DVD we will install Ubuntu from scratch again.

This are the 3 cases where I got the dreaded `Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed` error. The first time I got this, I tried to install Ubuntu 3 o 4 more times before giving up. Most of the time is a faulty burned CD image. Followed by bad memory. Lastly a faulty HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Your pastebin file shows that there is a "Invalid System Disk... Disk I/O Error..." at line number 752. So, I suspect that there is a faulty HDD issue. Try checking your hard disk by installing another OS or checking the disk.

Note: I am not an Ubuntu expert but I noticed something in you pastebin file and hence, thought it would be nice to bring in to notice.