# How to run Gnome disk utility

Tags: gnome

The Gnome disk utility is installed but there seems to be no way of running it. There is nothing on the sidebar or the desktop. How do I run it?

Comment: Have you tried to launch it through a terminal ? Just type in : `gnome-disks`. Depending on your needs, you might want to try `gparted` as well

Comment: type `disks` in dash search bar

Comment: OK the monitor on the computer with Gnome I just bought does not work any more so I will have to take it back. The computer I am typing this on tries to write to DVD but says that a blank DVD is full.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/317241/can-i-use-ubuntu-to-diagnose-hard-drive-or-ram-problems-in-windows/317292#317292 for nice screenshots.

Answer (score 7):

I am on **Lubuntu 14.04**.
Install the package **gnome-disk-utility**.
However, to run it in a terminal, type **gnome-disks**.

In my localized German version of the menu, it appears under
**Accessories** > **Drives**.

Comment: Isn't there a commandline for this?

Answer (score 2):

**Gnome Disc Utility** is now called **Disks**

To run **disks** open the dash by clicking the Ubuntu logo on the side bar.

Then type in **disks** and click the disks icon to launch.

[image: disks]

If it's no longer installed, then install the package ***gnome-disk-utility***

Comment: I can see Gnome disks. When I click on that the logo gets big. Clicking on that makes it small again. How is it meant to run?

Answer (score 1):

Type `Disk Utility` in the unity dash panel or

`crtl+alt+t`

and type

`palimpsest`

Comment: palimpsest: command not found

Comment: In 14.04 they changed it to `gnome-disks` in 12.04 it's `palimpsest`