# Ubuntu halts after few seconds of starting and nothing works command, virtual terminal, GUI

Tags: 14.04, kernel, ubuntu-gnome

I installed ubuntu and after a fresh restart the sysyem goes to halt. 
It shows following error in the virtual terminal  
 *[484.269470] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_find_entry:1309: inode #2093097: comm dconf-service: reading directory lblock 0*

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the output from the terminal, it seems there's some problem with partition `inodes`, you should try below:-

**NOTE:-** `fsck`/`e2fsck` works on unmounted partitions, so you first need to boot to recovery, and then run `fsck` from there by the option given or by dropping running to root shell prompt and then running the below commands.

Run:

```
umount /path/to/device
fsck -t ext3 /dev/whatever
```

followed by:

```
e2fsck -f /dev/whatever
```

**EDIT:-**

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilesystemTroubleshooting) and [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/fsck.8.html) will probably help you alot!

Comment: Generally it goes to halt within a short time but even i get to open terminal and enter some commands it returns Input/Output Error

Comment: Then, probably `fsck` is not the issue, you may need to reformat the partition and reinstall Ubuntu, if that doesn't fix it then maybe a HDD issue, BTW are you sure your HDD is perfect ( did it work?) ?

Comment: What about recovery mode, can you access it from grub.

Comment: Yes i can access recovery mode from grub.

Comment: Then try my answer and tell me what you get!

Comment: Fsck from util-linux 2.20.1 /dev/sda1: 178254/3662848 files (0.2% non-contiguous) , 1321602/14647949 blocks  that is ongoing and count in file cheking is not increasing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24659/discussion-between-sharad-gautam-and-algosig).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a HHD problem, you can check potential problems with SMART on live session, [more info here](https://askubuntu.com/a/317292/404268)

Comment: Why woukd it boot and pass login screen and gimo to main screen, if it had HDD problem?