# I was given a laptop with a corrupted XP OS on it-- like to install Ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot

I was recently given a laptop with a "corrupted" XP OS on it, according to the old owner. From what he says, XP will start to boot and then completely crash.  I haven't seen the laptop yet, but I'd like to explore the possibility of wiping the OS and installing Ubuntu. Would this be a possibility?  Should I look at burning Ubuntu to CD and trying to boot from the CD, or is there a way to get rid of the OS mess first, and then try and boot from a blank laptop?  I am not sure how the XP system got corrupted (whether it's a virus or perhaps something wrong with the laptop itself).  Any advice or tips on how to approach this (or whether it's worth it) would be greatly appreciated.  Thank yoU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to *wipe* the computer first. By installing with the option "Replace Microsoft Windows ..." the Windows partitions will be removed and formatted before Ubuntu is installed.

So on the software side, there is nothing to fear. You should still be careful if the "corruption" doesn't stem from old and/or unstable hardware. Do a [stress test](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/11/stress-test-your-ubuntu-computer-with-stress/) to be sure that your hardware is reliable. Also do run the [Memory test](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187573/memtest-with-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd) from the Ubuntu live system.