# Help booting/installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, 14.04

So I have been trying to boot 14.04 but I keep getting an error screen.

Some relevant information is that I wiped my hard drive because Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 both were not working properly.

I wanted my laptop just to have Ubuntu 14.04. I have looked into this problem before posting here and some suggest to boot from a live CD and work from there, but I do not have a live CD and do not know how to make one either.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some brief google searches suggest this likely to be a problem with bad RAM, which *could* explain your previous issues with both Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04.

My suggestion to confirm this would be to boot into a Linux distro (e.g. Ubuntu) off of some removable media and attempt to run a memory test for at least several hours.

If you have access to another computer, you could use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) in either Windows or Linux to create a bootable thumb drive of Ubuntu 12.04, and follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187573/memtest-with-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd) during boot to access the menu allowing you to test your RAM.