# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS hangs in Lenovo G510

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in Lenovo Essential G510 laptop after erasing Windows 8 which came pre-installed(after trying Windows 8 and Ubuntu dual boot with hanging problem persisting). The system hangs in below two situations:
1. Watching videos in youtube in fullscreeen mode.
2. Copying files from the shared local area network.

Laptop specification :
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200M CPU @ 2.50GHz, 4 GB RAM.
Network controller- Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 wireless network adapter(rev 01)
Ethernet controller- Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet(rev 10)(subsystem Lenovo device 3801)
VGA Compatible controller- Intel Corp 4th gen integrated graphics controller(rev 06).

I switched to ubuntu with lot of expectations but this glitch is bothering me. 
Please tell the fix..

Comment: Are these actions work as expected under Windows 8? I would suggest you to run memtest for your RAM, check this thread for instructions: [Memtest with Ubuntu 12.04 live CD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187573/memtest-with-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd)

Comment: Thank you..Yes, it was working very good with Windows 8. I dont have dual boot. Now I have erased Windows and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS...

Answer (score 0):

We believe it might be due to he missing of nvidia drive. So you can use the below command and install,

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

After doing this please check whether the issue goes off.

Comment: For the first run of the command system hanged in the half way during the process but the second time successfully nvidia-current was installed. So the 1st problem I asked is solved.

Comment: Now youtube videos stream without problem in full screen mode. But it still hangs while copying files from shared local area network..any solution?