# Kernel Panic while booting Ubuntu 14.04.1 Live USB, on Lenovo G50-70

Tags: 14.04

Recently I received a Windows computer as a gift. Now I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1.

After using Universal USB installer to create a bootable flash drive from Ubuntu 14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso. I attempted to try Ubuntu without installing it to make sure it worked okay.

After my computer showed the ubuntu startup screen, the kernel crashed with an error.

Computer specifics:

- Windows 8.1
- Intel Core i5-4210U
- Lenovo G50-70

Here's a screenshot of the error message:
 [image: error]

***Edit:*** After creating a bootable flash drive via LiLi from ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso, booting was successful.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/590398/edit) your question and add the error message.

Comment: @MadMike As requested.

Comment: Disable UEFI and/or SecureBoot. On your BIOS, try to load the default values before attempting this.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I did that before attempting to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: @TheBestOne Try to force Puppylinux or Debian to boot. And try with UNetBoootin (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) instead of Universal USB Installer.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I was able to get it to work. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: Can you please share with us what you did to get it up and running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21499/discussion-between-thebestone-and-ismael-miguel).

Comment: I wasn't saying on a chat, but on an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Given the kernel panic you've shown (the Windows one might help as well), I would have to wager that this is a memory / RAM issue.

What you should do for the time being to pinpoint the actual issue:

1. Reboot your machine.
2. When the boot menu shows up (shown below), select the first `Memory Test`.
3. Let it run. Note any errors.

Please post back with any info from the test(s).

[image]

Comment: My Windows OS is working perfectly fine :) The grub on the live USB doesn't have those memory test options. I did an extensive memory test in Windows and found no problems with my computer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I neglected the fact that you're booting from USB. :)
See this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187573/memtest-with-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd

Comment: The kernel crashes before I can reach the language menu mentioned by the answer. Check disk for defects is available from grub. It merely restarts my computer.

Comment: Hmmmm...Now I'm stumped :(
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm going to attempt to try it with ubuntu-14.04.2. If it works, I'll comment down here.

Comment: Hmm... It worked.

Comment: Nice! :)
Dunno why that happened to begin with...

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the newest version(14.04.2) and then using LiLi to create the live USB successfully solved the problem.